# Amplify Datastore not saving but correctly querying relational model

Tags: amazon-web-services, graphql, aws-amplify, aws-appsync, datastore

The schemas are as follows:

```
type User @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  userEmail: AWSEmail!
  userName: String!
  userPassword: String!
  userGoals: [Goal] @hasMany(indexName: "byUser", fields: ["id"])
}

type Goal @model @auth(rules: [{allow: public}]) {
  id: ID!
  goalStart: AWSDateTime!
  goalEnd: AWSDateTime
  goalCategory: CategoryTypes!
  goalCurrentDuration: DurationBeat!
  goalTargetDuration: DurationBeat!
  goalPercentage: Float
  userID: ID! @index(name: "byUser")
  goalActivities: [Activity] @hasMany(indexName: "byGoal", fields: ["id"])
  goalOfUser: User! @belongsTo
}
```

I save a Goal using:

```
  Future<void> createGoal(String userID, CategoryTypes category,
      DurationBeat targetDuration) async {
    final Goal goal = Goal(
        userID: userID,
        goalCategory: category,
        goalTargetDuration: targetDuration,
        goalCurrentDuration: DurationBeat(
            durationHours: 0, durationMinutes: 0, durationSeconds: 0),
        goalPercentage: 0,
        goalStart: _today, //Local datetime variable
        goalEnd: null, //Null when the goal is current. Date assigned when the user sets new goal.
        goalOfUser: global.currentUser //Globally accessible user instance
);
    await Amplify.DataStore.save(goal);
  }
```

When this function runs, nothing shows up in the database. **(It saved correctly when I omit goalOfUser, but I made it a required field to establish a bi-directional relationship)**

Finally, I request the data back using this function

```
  Future<Goal> getLatestGoal(CategoryTypes category, String userId) async {
    final record = await Amplify.DataStore.query(Goal.classType,
        where: Goal.USERID
            .eq(userId)
            .and(Goal.GOALCATEGORY.eq(category))
            .and(Goal.GOALEND.eq(null)),
        sortBy: [Goal.GOALEND.ascending()]);
    return record.first;
  }
```

Surprisingly, this function returns the data that I "saved".

```
Goal {id=710ddbeb-89b5-4bcd-9623-8232b4e8a545, goalStart=2022-07-23T04:00:00.000000000Z, goalEnd=null, goalCategory=FITNESS, goalCurrentDuration=DurationBeat {durationSeconds=0, durationMinutes=0, durationHours=0}, goalTargetDuration=DurationBeat {durationSeconds=0, durationMinutes=5, durationHours=1}, goalPercentage=0.0, userID=190c7bd1-02ad-4ab1-970d-49b8e6f7a9f8, goalOfUser=User {id=190c7bd1-02ad-4ab1-970d-49b8e6f7a9f8, userEmail=charlesrichardsonusa@gmail.com, userName=Charbo, userPassword=password, createdAt=2022-07-19T20:23:09.797000000Z, updatedAt=2022-07-23T05:06:18.321000000Z}, createdAt=null, updatedAt=null}
```

I noticed that the attribute `createdAt` is null. I assume this means that it is only saved locally, but I do not understand why it wont sync remotely.

My question is:
How can I debug the Amplify.DataStore.save() function to determine exactly what is going wrong?
OR
Point out what I did wrong. I cant find the typo.

Comment: have you found a solution for this?

Comment: @benwl I have yet to figure out the cause of this behavior. I have stepped away from this project for the past few months, but plan to return to it soon. When I refamiliarize myself, I will see if I can give it another go, and if a solution comes up, I will provide an update here.